# Missing variables in BuildConfig Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

Before updating Groovy to Kotlin, I had shared variables in the BuildConfig and depending on the build variant (release or debug), these variables took their corresponding value:

release.properties:

```
apiUrl="https://api.url.com"
```

debug.properties:

```
apiUrl="https://api.url.test"
```

BuidlConfig (debug for example):

```
public final class BuildConfig {
    ...
    public static final String apiUrl = "https://api.url.test";
}
```

Now when build my project:

```
val apiUrl: String = BuildConfig.apiUrl

Unresolved reference: apiUrl
```

I have this in my gradle.properties:

```
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.ase.app"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.ase.app"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isDebuggable = false
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
        debug {
            isDebuggable = true
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}
```

**My solution (15/09/2023):**

In `build.gradle.kts` add:

```
...
androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().withBuildType("release")) { variant ->
        variant.buildConfigFields.put("apiUrl", BuildConfigField("String", getProperty("release.properties", "API_URL"), ""))
    }
    onVariants(selector().withBuildType("debug")) { variant ->
        variant.buildConfigFields.put("apiUrl", BuildConfigField("String", getProperty("debug.properties", "API_URL"), ""))
    }
}
...
fun getProperty(fileName: String, propertyName: String): String {
    val propertiesFile = File(fileName)
    if (propertiesFile.exists()) {
        val properties = Properties()
        properties.load(FileInputStream(propertiesFile))
        return properties.getProperty(propertyName) ?: ""
    } else {
        throw GradleException("$fileName not found!")
    }
}
```

In the same level of `gradle.properties`, I've added two files `release.properties` and `debug.properties` with the content:

```
API_URL="..."
```

Comment: post whole build.gradle file plz

Comment: Where is `BuildConfig` located?